# How to set tag to a button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using `[button.tag] = 50;`
But it is not working.

I want to set tag to buttons.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That would be:

```
button.tag = 50;
```

Do yourself a favor and take the time to read through Apples [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html), in this case specifically about the [Dot Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17) and declared properties.